# Kubernetes Ingress encode decode issue

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

There is a url like

```
http://host/a%7b%7c
```

If I add annotation in ingress:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: dev/$1
```

after ingress it will change to

```
host/dev/a|b|c
```

I don't want ingress decode this url, I need it **keeps**

```
host/dev/a%7b%7c
```

I try another way, I add this annotation in ingress

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
   rewrite ^ $request_uri;
   rewrite /(.*) /dev/$1;
```

After ingress it is encoded

The uri change to

```
host/dev/a%257b%257c
```

I just want it constant

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What about `rewrite ^ /dev$request_uri;`?

Comment: I try rewrite ^ /dev$request_uri not works